# newer_than parameter value is being ignored in API calls to get messages

Tags: yammer

There is a bug in the messages.xml API call

https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.xml?newer_than=[NewerThanID]  (.json behaves the same)

This has been working for the past year and half, but sometime around June 23, 2014 this stopped working correctly.

If you pass in the value for newer_than (message id), this was returning the messages directly after the newer_than (message id). Now, the call is returning the most recent items, no matter what value for newer_than is passed in.

Can someone at Yammer please check this as this changed sometime in the last two weeks.

Going backwards (older_than) works as expected.

Comment: Do you ask in yammer.com? What's the real question here?... Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is addressed as a bug report to a third-party software provider, rather than a request for help from the Stack Overflow community. See [this Help Center page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support) for the official policy on using Stack Overflow for third-party support.

Answer (score 0):

The newer_than parameter returns the most recent 20 messages newer than the id you have specified. You can check the id of the last message fetched and append older_than to get messages newer than the one you have specified and older than the 20th most recent one.
That should work!

Comment: This makes getting all new messages impossible; in the past, it would return in sequence; Meaning there are 100 messages ahead of you, by passing in the newer_than value of the most recent message received, I then get the next 20 until the system is caught up.

This worked correctly until about June 21; this requires a code change on our part now because we have to restart the 'Older Than' value every day to get all the new messages.

In the past if there 100 messages ahead of our newer than id, we could get the next 20 in sequence, please have someone investigate this with the high priority.

Comment: @Corby Please note that you are discussing this on a public, community-driven Q&A site. Your request to "have someone investigate this" is likely not being read by anyone officially associated with the product.